# Counting words from a file

Tags: java, io

for this program I have to write I'm given an input file of strings that has a line (or lines) of text, for example: "The high HIGH cat High jumped (WOW 6SOFT)". From this line I have to scan the file, count the number of times a word appears (regardless of capitalization), and then output it to a formatted file. If a digit comes before a word, the word should not be counted. The format has to be started with the count right justified in three spaces, followed by another space, followed by the word counted in lower case.

```
package InClass;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CountWords {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputFile);

        boolean next = scanner.hasNext();
        ArrayList<String> inputWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> outputWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (next) { // Adds all the strings to an array list
            inputWords.add(scanner.next());
            for (int i = 0; i < inputWords.size(); i++) {
                inputWords.get(i).toLowerCase();
            }
        }
        while (next) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputWords.size(); i++) {
                String word = inputWords.get(i);
                int count = 1;
                if (!Character.isDigit(word.charAt(0))) {
                    outputWords.add(inputWords.get(i));
                    if (outputWords.contains(word)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                } else {
                    inputWords.remove((i));
                }
                for (int j = 0; i < outputWords.size(); j++) {
                    word = outputWords.get(i);
                    writer.printf("%3s" + "%1s\n", count, word);
                }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
}
}
```

My tester file is giving me an error saying there is a NoSuchElementException for only one of the tester classes, which is testing two words. Here is the test class giving the error"

```
@Test
public void testTwoWords() {
    try {
        File inputFile = new File(INPUT);
        File outputFile = new File(OUTPUT);

        // If assert fails it is (usually) because the file was (wrongly)
        // left open in an earlier run.
        // Using a file manager application (e.g. explorer), go to project
        // directory and delete it.
        // Make sure that your program closes these files before ending.
        if (inputFile.exists()) {
            assertTrue("Your program left \"" + INPUT
                    + "\" open in a previous test.", inputFile.delete());
        }
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            assertTrue("Your program left \"" + OUTPUT
                    + "\" open in a previous test.", outputFile.delete());
        }

        // create INPUT file
        PrintWriter input = new PrintWriter(inputFile);
        input.println("King");
        input.println("");
        input.println("");
        input.println("");
        input.println("hill");
        input.close();

        // invoke program
        CountWords.main(null);

        // verify OUTPUT file exists and is empty
        assertTrue("Output file doesn't exist", outputFile.exists());
        Scanner output = new Scanner(outputFile);
        String actual = output.nextLine();
        assertEquals("Incorrect result", "  1 king", actual);
        actual = output.nextLine();
        assertEquals("Incorrect result", "  1 hill", actual);
        assertFalse("There should be no more data", output.hasNext());
        output.close();

        // delete I/O files
        assertTrue("Input file could not be deleted", inputFile.delete());
        assertTrue("Output file could not be deleted", outputFile.delete());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fail("No exception should be thrown");
    }

}
```

Finally, my other testers are saying "Your program left "input.txt" open in a previous test". Any idea why? Thank you tons in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The for loop for your outputWords is using the i loop counter instead of j.

```
for (int j = 0; i < outputWords.size(); j++) {
                    word = outputWords.get(i);
                    writer.printf("%3s" + "%1s\n", count, word);
                }
```

Change that to

```
for (int j = 0; i < outputWords.size(); j++) {
                    word = outputWords.get(j);//NEED TO USE J HERE
                    writer.printf("%3s" + "%1s\n", count, word);
                }
```

The reason the other tests are failing is because you are apparently supposed to delete the output files after each test is run.

Comment: I don't fully understand how to do that, is it just    inputFile.delete() ? I tried adding that to my code but it didn't work